# QT Designer. Установкой background-color для PushButton и анимация нажатия

Tags: qt-designer, qpushbutton, background-color

Следующая проблема с установкой background-color.
Просто для примера поместил 2 PushButton на форму.

[image: Пример PushButton]

Попытался установить background-color в styleSheet для PushButton.
[image: PushButton styleSheet]

Но фон не изменился. В документации прочитал, что такая проблема может возникать из-за значения границ. Изменил границу и фон поменялся.

[image: PushButton styleSheet2]

Но! Теперь кнопка выглядит как простой Label. При кликаньи мышкой нет анимации нажатия.

[image: PushButton styleSheet3]

Сам код этих двух кнопок:

```
from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(400, 300)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(parent=Form)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 50, 107, 101))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(154, 153, 150);\n"
"border: 2px;\n"
"")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(parent=Form)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 50, 107, 101))
        self.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet("")
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "TestButton"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Form", "ClearButton"))
```

Рабочий файл:

```
from PyQt6 import QtWidgets
from Buttons import Ui_Form
import sys


class mywindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(mywindow, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_Form()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
application = mywindow()
application.show()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Удалось добиться успехов в самом Desighner только при выставлении **Форма - Предпросмотр в - стиль Windows** и только в этом случае.
При запуске из PyCHarm кнопка является просто цветным прямоугольником без какой-либо реакции на нажатия.

Собственно вопрос, как изменить фон PushButton, чтобы кнопка визуально осталась кнопкой с соответствующей анимацией.

PS. Темная тема подтянулась из темы Linux. (manjaro если это важно). В светлом варианте тоже самое.

Постарался как можно более подробнее описать проблему. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: QPushButton {  background-color:rgb(154, 153, 150) }

Comment: В Desigher'e в styleSheet кнопки попробовал: QPushButton { background-color:rgb(154, 153, 150) }. Без результата. По старой схеме, изменяется фоновый цвет, только при QPushButton { border: 5px; background-color:rgb(154, 153, 150) }

Comment: может тема дизайнера кривая, попробуйте `Form/Preview in/Fusion style`, а лучше запустить `designer -style Fusion`

Comment: Запуск с ключом -style Fusion помог. Большое спасибо!

Comment: Но если в styleSheet определяю либо border, либо border radius, то кнопка опять умирает....буду дальше копать. Спасибо еще раз.

Comment: ну там же надо всякие `QPushButton:pressed` определять https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/stylesheet-examples.html